# Categories not adding trailing slash

Tags: categories

In my general config I have enabled URLS to have trailing slashes.

```
'addTrailingSlashesToUrls' => true,
```

This is working for products and entries. But it is not working on Categories. Category links are not adding trailing slashes.

Is there some additional config I need to add/setup or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to generate the links? Have you made any modifications to the stock public `.htaccess` file (assuming you're running Apache)?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry Brad. As I went to check the code I realised, I was using {{ category.uri }} instead of {{ category.url }}.

Comment: Incidentally what exactly is uri?

Comment: Ahh... would you mind adding that as an answer? There's a good venn diagram here on URI vs. URL vs. URN: https://danielmiessler.com/study/url-uri/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops! Sorry. As I went to check the code I realised, I was using `{{ category.uri }}` instead of `{{ category.url }}`.